# How to introduce new terms that may be used interchangeably in a formal context?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am writing a scientific paper. I was thinking whether there is any difference in the following.

> Technique X, also known as technique Y, is the most commonly used process to ...

or

> Technique X or Y is the most commonly used process to ...

Comment: re: "whether there is any difference:" The second version could imply Technique Y is **not** the same as Technique X.

Comment: No, you want *... the process most commonly used to ...*.   It’s not “a used process to do” because that doesn't make sense. It is a process used to do something.

Answer (score 1):

first one is correct.You can still improvise it to :

> Technique X alias Y is the most commonly used process to ...

Reference :http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/also%20known%20as

Comment: _improvise_? Did you mean _improve_?

Comment: @ThomasFrancois exactly.